# Sails doesn't create mysql table

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

I try to use my sails project on a server. I installed mysql.
When i call the request to create a user, sails doesn't automatically create the table "User".

I get this error:

```
sails-hook-sockets :: connected to Sails admin message bus.
Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:
 Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'mooz.user' doesn't exist
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/home/mooz/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:48:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/mooz/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:83:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/mooz/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:271:23)
    at Parser.write (/home/mooz/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77:12)
    at Protocol.write (/home/mooz/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/mooz/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:92:28)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:710:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:382:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:378:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:143:7)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:113:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:511:21)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/mooz/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:135:48)
    at PoolConnection.Connection.query (/home/mooz/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:197:25)
    at __FIND__ (/home/mooz/api/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/adapter.js:836:20)
    at afterwards (/home/mooz/api/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:84:5)
    at /home/mooz/api/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:40:7
    at Ping.onPing [as _callback] (/home/mooz/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:94:5)
    at Ping.Sequence.end (/home/mooz/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
    at Ping.Sequence.OkPacket (/home/mooz/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:105:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/mooz/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:271:23)
    at Parser.write (/home/mooz/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77:12)
    at Protocol.write (/home/mooz/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/mooz/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:92:28)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:710:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:382:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:378:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:143:7)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:113:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:511:21)

Details:  Error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'mooz.user' doesn't exist
```

Here my model User.js

```
var Waterline = require('waterline');

// Define your collection (aka model)
var User = Waterline.Collection.extend({

  attributes: {

    connection:'mysql',
    tableName:'user',

    id: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true
    },

    username: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    }

  }
});
```

My model.js:

```
module.exports.models = {
 connection: 'mysql',
  migrate: 'safe'
};
```

My connection.js:

```
module.exports.connections = {

  mysql: {
    adapter   : 'sails-mysql',
    host      : 'localhost',
    user      : 'user',
    port      : 3306,
    password  : 'test',
    database  : 'mooz'
  }

};
```

And my userController

```
module.exports = {
    createUser: function(req, res){
    var params = req.params.all();

    User.create({username: params.username, id: params.id}).exec(function createUser(err,created){
      return res.json({
        notice: 'Created user ' + params.username
      });
    });
  }
};
```

I don't understand why sails can't create automatically the table, did i forget something? Is there any command to do?

Thanks.

EDIT: Resolved with dev environnement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to set `migrate: 'alter'` in model.js, and `sails lift` again.

Comment: If you are running sails in production mode, it will always use `migrate: safe` regardless of your settings. Try running it in dev mode to create the tables first. (Note that it might be set by the system wide `NODE_ENV` variable on your server)